# Toast background changing to match Activity's Theme

Tags: android, themes

I have created a custom theme for my activities that they all use. In the theme, I set android:background, and this happens to cause any dialog or toast message to look very strange.

How do I prevent toast and the other dialogs from absorbing the theme's properties?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can easily create custom toast by the following code:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, resTxtId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = toast.getView();
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_bkg);
TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
/*here you can do anything with text*/
toast.show();
```

Or you can instantiate a completely custom toast:

```
Toast toast = new Toast(context);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
toast.setView(view);
toast.show();
```

Dialog customizing is a more complex routine. But there is similar workaround.

Comment: Javacadabra answer is better in my opinion

Comment: Am I reading the question wrong? But the question asks how to PREVENT it from being customised, and you are stating HOW to customise it?

Comment: @WORRMS, you're right, but... As far as theme is changed, any toast that doesn't apply this theme is a custom toast (because we need to "re-style" it back)

Answer (score 32):

I realise the question has been answered and the post is quite old at this stage. However I thought I would leave an answer for those who come across this question.

I ran into trouble with this issue today and the way I resolved it was by displaying my Toast messages like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checking login details...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

As opposed to this (presuming the message is being called from within a View):

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Checking login details...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It cleared up the issues I was having. Anyways hope it helps. Here is link to my question on similar topic.

[Toast background color being changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244317/toast-background-color-being-changed/14244786#14244786)

Comment: great comment, thank you! btw, the first & accepted answer didn't work for me, but your solution does.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same question as the OP and this worked for me great!

Comment: This is a very simple solution that avoids creating your own toast or having to mess around with styles.xml.  I like it!

Comment: For me `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` worked!

Answer (score 5):

here comes complete example, to be used for customized Toast across activities.

**displayToast**

```
// display customized Toast message
    public static int SHORT_TOAST = 0;
    public static int LONG_TOAST = 1;
    public static void displayToast(Context caller, String toastMsg, int toastType){

        try {// try-catch to avoid stupid app crashes
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(caller);

            View mainLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, null);
            View rootLayout = mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_icon_notification);
            TextView text = (TextView) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText(toastMsg);

            Toast toast = new Toast(caller);
            //toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
            if (toastType==SHORT_TOAST)//(isShort)
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            else
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(rootLayout);
            toast.show();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {// to avoid stupid app crashes
            Log.w(TAG, ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

and **toast_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:background="#DAAA"
              >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
               />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```