# Toast background color being changed

Tags: android, xml, styles, toast

I am working on a project and set the background of the application to white by doing the following:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">140dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

This works a charm however the problem is that the toast messages are now being displayed with a white background. The strange thing is that I integrated a splash screen into the project and when the user logs in the toast message is displayed normally.

It is really strange and would appreciate any help on the issue.

EDIT: ADDED SCREENSHOT SHOWING ISSUE. The screenshot is taken just as the initial toast (with unwanted effect) is fading out and the new one (with default) is fading in.

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I resolved the issue. The reason for the change in the Toast background color was due to the way I was passing in the context of the View object it was contained inside.

The following line of code would cause the background color to change to the unwanted white color:

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Checking login details...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This line of code would return the Toast to the default system style:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checking login details...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I am not sure if there is a huge problem with fixing it like this as I am only learning. If anyone can see a problem please share. It seems to be working just fine though.

Comment: This was very helpful

Comment: In my case I was using a custom layout, and solved the problem by setting the background of the text view of the toast.

Answer (score 0):

For me using `getApplicationContext()` wasn't an option, and for others that have this same issue, you can just set the Toast back to the default settings like so:

```
//Create your Toast with whatever params you need
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Refreshing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  

//Set the background for the toast using android's default toast_frame.
//Optionally you can set the background color to #646464 which is the
//color of the frame
View view = toast.getView();
view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.toast_frame); 

//Get the TextView for the toast message so you can customize
TextView toastMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.message); 

//Set background color for the text.
toastMessage.setBackgroundColor((Color.parseColor("#646464"))); 
toast.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

An addition to WInthrop's answer. Instead of setting the background color of the textbox as #646464, it can be set to transparent so that the toast looks like the original translucent toast

```
private void showToast(Context context,String msg,int duration){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,msg,duration);

        View view = toast.getView();
        view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.toast_frame);

        TextView toastMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);

        toastMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        toast.show();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what worked for me. I took [Sachin Murali G' s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38188656/7342155) code

```
 private void showToast(Context context, String msg, int duration) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
        View view = toast.getView();
        view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.toast_frame);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        TextView text = view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        text.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_toast));
        text.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
        toast.show();
    }
```

and added `custom_toast.xml` in the `drawable` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="22dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="12dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="12dp"/>
</shape>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(0xFF00ddff);
```

Comment: Could you please write a bit more than just a one-liner? Please add some context, ...