# Custom Toast for Google TV

Tags: android, themes, overlay, toast, google-tv

I am creating an overlay for google TV. I have created a transparent theme so that the broadcast can be seen through the application as follows:

Styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Invisible" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

When not using this theme I can display a custom toast with a picture using:

```
             View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));

                        // Toast...
                        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setView(layout);
                        toast.show();
```

However when I use this theme it does not display and will only display the standard toast:

```
        Toast.makeText(this, "This game is over. Start a new game.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The toast is just displaying a picture in the middle of the screen so does not need to be complex.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create an activity with that layout instead. Start the activity instead of invoking the toast.

Answer (score 0):

Toasts will incorporate the theme used by the currently active activity. So as Leon stated, if you create an activity with the theme you want the toast will inherit the theme. See: [Toast background changing to match Activity's Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020286/toast-background-changing-to-match-activitys-theme)