# android override toast background from style

Tags: android

I am tying to override the toast background using "android:toastFrameBackground" attribute in styles.xml.

But it's giving me error stating :

```
No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:toastFrameBackground'.
```

What can be the reason ?

Comment: Just guessing maybe will work @android:style/toastFrameBackground

Comment: nops....... not working

Comment: Have you tried like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020286/toast-background-changing-to-match-activitys-theme ?

Comment: That will work, but now toast has been used at many places, so its better to change in style

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also looking to change the background from styles